# Hide content but respond to :hover

Tags: css, oocss

I am working on a pure oocss approach to creating the charms as found in Windows 8. I have the Dock class finished, but am having problems with figuring out how to "expand" the charm when the mouse is moved over a docked area. I know there are ways to hide content but have the browser respond to the :hover event of Charm. If you have any ideas, let me know.

**Dock**

Docks content to the edge of the screen.

```
.dock 
{
    position:                       fixed;

    height:                         auto;

    width:                          auto;
}

.dock--top
{
    width:                          100%;

    top:                            0;
}

.dock--bottom
{
    width:                          100%;

    bottom:                         0;
}

.dock--left
{
    height:                         100%;

    width:                          auto;

    left:                           0;
}

.dock--right
{
    height:                         100%;

    right:                          0;
}
```

**Charm**

Island containing the content.

```
.charm
{
    padding:                        24px;
}

.charm:hover
{

}
```

**Html**

```
<div class="charm dock dock--right">


</div>
```

I tried padding it and setting the width to 1px but had no luck. On my original plan I would have applied the background-color when the move moved over it so it did not render a line going down the side of the screen.

This is as close as I have gotten but its ugly:

```
.charm__body
{
    width:                           0;

    visibility:                      collapse;
}

.charm:hover
{
    background:                     blue;
}

.charm:hover .charm__body
{
    width:                          auto;

    visibility:                     visible;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a transparent div, positioned absolutely, and make it work as a hover trigger.

Comment: I thought about it but know older versions of Internet Explorer do not support opacity without the .filter polyfill. Let me edit my question and add my trial attempt. It's somewhat working but it leaves a small margin and I would have to write additional modifiers for it to be displayed when docked to the top or bottom.

Comment: Actually, you don't need opacity, just define its size and of course, set the background to transparent (in case some CSS is overriding the default value).